Do I need to have ATXRaspi for raspberry Pi (3 B+) if I am using a touch display for a shutdown/restart
I am a newbie in raspberry Pi, and I am using it for a project which would eventually become a base station for the project I am doing for my course project.
I am using raspberry Pi 3B+ and I am also using Raspberry Pi 7" touch screen display. I was told to use ATXRaspi for a graceful shutdown/restart option, but do I still need to use ATXRaspi if I am using a touch screen? If I choose shutdown option from the display, doesn't it allow a shutdown for the whole system including raspberry PI or it applies solely for that touch screen?
Please do advise me on this and I would really appreciate if anybody could give me some advice/guidance

the RPi does not power off on its own when shutdown completes ... you do not need to use ATXRaspi, you can pull the power plug

This question is similar to: Raspberry Pi GPIO shutdown/reboot options. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
